# Communication between front end app and backend app in cloud foundry

Tags: java, html, cloud-foundry, paas

I am shifting my applications to cloud foundry. I have pushed my front end as an html app and my backend REST services provider as a Java app. Now, I want to make HTTP calls to my backend java app from my html app. I know I can hardcode java app's url, but what is the **best practice** here? I can't seem to find anything after considerable world wide web search.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use a dedicated directory service like Eureka to discover your backend Java app. Chris Richardson provides a good overview here:

http://microservices.io/patterns/client-side-discovery.html

Spring Boot/Spring Cloud make it extremely easy to a Eureka server up and running, and for your Java app to register with the server:

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/

For your HTML app, you will want to use a Javascript client library to access your directory service, like this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client